# I can not show the result of my service in the html component

Tags: .net, typescript, asp.net-core, angular7, angular-components

```
/* I am developing an example application with asp net core Web Api and angular 7. This should consume a service, but when I try to show it in the component it shows me that the object is undefined.*/

//Shortn.ts

enter code here
export interface Shortn {

  Url: string;
}
//HomeComponent.ts
MyMethod() {

    var url = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("MyObjectInput")).value;
    alert("desde componente: " + url);
    this.shortenerService.shortenUrl2(url).toPromise()
      .then(res => this.shortener = res as Shortn);

  }
//ShortenService .ts

import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Shortn } from '../models/shortn';

//ShortenService 
@Injectable()
export class ShortenService {
  private apiURL = this.baseUrl + "api/My/Generate";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { }
  shortenUrl(url: string): Observable<string> {
    alert("desde servicio: " + url);
    let shortener = { Url: url };
    //shortener.Url = url;
    return this.http.post<string>(this.apiURL, shortener);
  }
  shortenUrl2(url: string): Observable<Shortn> {
    alert("desde servicio: " + url);
    let shortener = { Url: url };
    //shortener.Url = url;
    return this.http.post<Shortn>(this.apiURL, shortener);
  }
  shortenUrl3(url: string): Observable<Shortn> {
    let shortener = { Url: url };
    return this.http.post<Shortn>(this.apiURL, shortener);
  }

}
//home.component.html
<pre>
  {{shortener.Url}}
</pre>
```

By pressing the button the app travels correctly to the service (with postman I can do it correctly), but wanting to show it in home.component.html tells me shortener is undefined. Try different ways, but always with the same result
The versions of the elements are:
Angular CLI: 7.2.3
Node: 11.6.0
OS: win32 x64
asp net core 2.2

Could you please help me?. Beforehand thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Check issues below in your code:

1. Js is case-sensitive,  you should define `url: string;` since the json returned from web api is `{"url":"api/My/Generate"}`

   ```
   export interface Shortn {
       url: string;
   }
   ```
2. You need to change `shortener` is undefined or initialize it since you may not set it before using it.

Option1:

```
    {{shortener ? shortener.url : "" }}
```

Option2:

```
private shortener: Shortn = { url:""};
```